# Why square root of $1$ is $1$ but square root of $0.1$ is $0.316$, again square root of $0.01$ is $0.1$?

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers

I would like to understand the reason behind this pattern:

$$\begin{align} 
\sqrt 1 &= 1 \\[4pt] 
\sqrt{0.1} &= 0.31622 \\[4pt] 
\sqrt{0.01} &= 0.1 \\[4pt] 
\sqrt{0.001} &=0.03162 \\[4pt] 
\sqrt{0.0001}&=0.01 \\[4pt] 
\sqrt{0.00001}&=0.003162 \end{align}$$

I expected $\sqrt{0.1}$ to "behave" in a similar way to $\sqrt 1$... Why this intermittent pattern? What does $3162\ldots$  represent? Does it represent an irrational number like $\pi$ or a ratio like Fibonacci?

Edit:

As some comments have kindly let me see, it all comes from $\sqrt{10} =3.16227766,$ so my question becomes: what does this number represent? I notice it's really close to $\pi,$ are the two things related? Also still not clear why this intermittent pattern as to why for example $\sqrt{1} = 1$ and $\sqrt{0.01}=0.1$ and so on and they are not something like $0.31622...$

Comment: Have you considered $\sqrt{10}$?

Comment: Well, $0.01 = 10^{-2}.$ so...

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is it about this that isn't already obvious?  Notice that $\sqrt{10}=3.1622\dots$.  Are you confused about why $\sqrt{10}=3.1622\dots$?  If so, what do you know about the definition of square roots?...  As for why $\sqrt{0.1}$ is like that... recognize that $0.1 = \frac{10}{100}$ and so $\sqrt{0.1}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{100}}$

Comment: 0.1 = 1/10 and root of 10 is an irrational number. On the other hand, 0.01 = 1/100 and root of 100 is 10, a natural number. Apply the same logic to 1/1000, 1/10000, etc.

Comment: @bananapeel22 now yes, please see edits

Comment: "*What does this number rapresent[sic]?  I notice it's really close to pi, are the two things related?*"  It represents the square root of 10..... That is... the positive real number who when squared equals ten.  It is the side-length of a square whose area is $10$... It has nothing to do with $\pi$ or any other constant like you seem to be looking for.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes I know the definition of square roots, I just don't get basically why $\sqrt{10}$ is completely different from $\sqrt{1}$ where one would expect a similar result

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz, also pi is somewhat similar to a circle and yet it's allover in nature, was wondering if this number is somewhat similar.

Comment: It has exactly the result that you should expect if you look at the definitions...  What "similar result" are you looking for?  $1$ is a square number and so $\sqrt{1}$ is an integer.  $100$ is a square number and so $\sqrt{100}$ is an integer.  $10$ is not a square number and so $\sqrt{10}$ is not an integer.  This number $\sqrt{10}\approx 3.1622\dots$ is "*halfway*" between $\sqrt{1}=1$ and $\sqrt{100}=10$ but where "*halfway*" is not halfway in terms of linear distance... but halfway in terms of *logarithmic* distance.

Comment: This is like asking why in the number sequence $0,0.5,1,1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5,\dots$ where each number in sequence is found by adding $0.5$ to the previous number... the number $0.5$ doesn't "*behave in a similar way*" to the numbers $1,2,3,\dots$.  Here, the numbers $1,3.1622\dots, 10, 31.622\dots, 100, 316.22\dots, \dots$ we multiply the previous number in the sequence by $3.1622\dots$ to get to the next number...  It behaves *exactly* like we should expect (*similarly if we were to divide by that amount instead like your sequence in your post*)

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz for the effort you put into explaining this to me, I understood

Comment: Everyone please be nice.  Just because the pattern is obvious to you doesn't mean it's obvious to everyone. I don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: In some sense, all math behaves exactly as we should expect. That doesn't mean that we do expect it the first time we encounter it.

Comment: To some extent, the alternating pattern is not so much a deep property of these square roots, as it is a consequence of how the decimal number system works (can't represent some numbers in a "nice" way). The choice of how to represent these values is, in a sense, about how we label them. You can get a more uniform view if you express everything in terms of $\sqrt{10}$ - then you get that the sequence is $1/(\sqrt{10})^{n}$, where $n$ is the number of zeros. So, let $d$ = $\sqrt{10}$, and you have ${1}/{d^0}, 1/d, 1/(dd), 1/(ddd), 1/(dddd)...$ The radical dissapears in the ones with even $n$.

Comment: Instead of looking at decimal numbers, look at the fractions they represent and then take square root. Then you will get the pattern.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don’t be discouraged by the comments.

The numbers you are considering are of the form $\sqrt{10^{-n}} = 10^{\frac{-n}{2}}$ where $n$ is a natural number. If $n$ is even then (like for $0.01, 0.0001$) then $\frac{n}{2}$ is also a natural number, call it $k$. Then $10^{\frac{-n}{2}}=10^{-k}$ which is $0.00..1000$ with 1 at k-th position. Now if $n$ is odd write $n=2k+1$ (like $0.1,0.001$) then $10^{-\frac{2k+1}{2}}=10^{-k-\frac{1}{2}} = 10^{-k}10^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 10^{-k} \cdot 3.16..$

So this is why the numbers seem “alternating”. The fact that $\sqrt{10}$ is 3.16… (which happens to be close to $\pi$) is just because that happens to be the number that when squared is $10$

Comment: https://fermatslibrary.com/s/why-is-pi-squared-so-close-to-10

Comment: This is a fantastic answer to a great (very thoughtful) question.

Comment: So I’m guessing it’s only ever possible to have period-2 properties like this (if we take any arbitrary number and not just 10) for our square roots, for the reason you cited?

Comment: @bob exactly. If you try cube roots, you'll find they have a period-3 cycle, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I was looking for. 
This is a really nice comunity, thank's everybody for stopping by.

Answer (score 7):

> yes I know the definition of square roots, I just don't get basically why $\sqrt{10}$ is completely different from $\sqrt{1}$ and $\sqrt{0.01},$ where one would expect a similar result

> As some comments have kindly let me seen, it all comes from $\sqrt{10}$

\begin{align}
\sqrt 1& =\sqrt\frac{1^2}{1^2} &&=\frac11&&&= 1\\
\sqrt{0.1}&=\sqrt\frac{1^2}{1^2\times10}&&=\frac1{\sqrt{10}}  &&&= 0.31622 \\
\sqrt{0.01}&=\sqrt\frac{1^2}{10^2}&&=\frac1{10} &&&= 0.1 \\ \sqrt{0.001}&=\sqrt\frac{1^2}{10^2\times10}&&=\frac1{10\sqrt{10}}  &&&=0.03162 \\ \sqrt{0.0001}&=\sqrt\frac{1^2}{100^2}&&=\frac1{100} &&&=0.01 \\ \sqrt{0.00001}&=\sqrt\frac{1^2}{100^2\times10}&&=\frac1{100\sqrt{10}} &&&=0.003162 \end{align}

Line 2 outputs a square root from an input that isn't a perfect square, so the result $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{10}}=\frac1{\sqrt2\sqrt5}$ is irrational; since each successive even-numbered line merely divides the previous one by $\sqrt{100}=10,$ every even-numbered line has the same string of significant digits.

The odd-numbered lines behave similarly but with perfect-square inputs and rational outputs.

This is why the irrationality, as evidenced by the presence of $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{10}}$ in the third column, alternates through the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Square roots (of positive real numbers) are equivalent to *halving* a power: $\sqrt {a^n} = a^{n/2}$.

Therefore, it's particularly convenient when you have a radicand that's expressible as an *even* power. E.g., $1 = 1^2$, $0.01 = \frac{1}{100} = \frac{1}{10^2}$, $0.0001 = \frac{1}{10000} = \frac{1}{10^4}$, and so forth. For cases like these, $\sqrt {\frac{1}{10^2}} = \frac{1}{10} = 0.1$, $\sqrt {\frac{1}{10^4}} = \frac{1}{10^2} = 0.01$, etc.

When you have a radicand that's an *odd* power of ten, then you get a number of the other form.